# SonarQube 5.2, LDAP plugin 1.5: com4j.ComException

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

AD login is not possible after upgrading from LDAP 1.4. In the TRACE log the following error message is logged:

```
DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsUsersProvider] Requesting details for user: xxxxxx
ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::Com4j::ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 8007203a Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The server is not operational. : .\com4j.cpp:217
```

Removing the LDAP settings from sonar.properties did not help. After downgrading to LDAP 1.4 everything works again. Did we miss some configuration setup?

Comment: In our envirionment we are using special characters in the CN part:  CN=Doe\\, John,OU=..., DC=... .

Comment: We installed SonarQube 5.2 and LDAP 1.5 (sonar.security.realm=LDAP, ldap.servers=... and no other LDAP settings => compatibilityMode=false) on a Windows 7 machine using 64 bits JavaSE 1.8 (amd64) in the same network: no errors!). Using the same software and config on a 2012 R2 machine:error. We found com4j-amd64.dll extracted from com4j-2.1.jar in web\deploy\plugins\ldap\META-INF\lib. Deletion only possible after stopping sonarqube.

Comment: I found this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17718 could this be an escaping problem?

Comment: Any update on this one? I am experiencing the same issues as you do.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but I am seeing first `successfully logged in user X\Y` then `Error from external users provider: exception Java::Com4j::ComException: 80040e37 (Unknown error) : An operations error occurred.`

Comment: A ticket was created to track and fix this issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/LDAP-49. It will be fixed in the upcoming version of the LDAP plugin that should be released very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDAP plugin 1.5.1 with fix for this issue ([LDAP-49](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/LDAP-49) is released and available for download from SonarQube's update center.

Refer to [SonarQube LDAP plugin documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) page:

LDAP 1.5.1 – Dec 02, 2015 – Compatible with SonarQube 5.2+ 
 Bug fixes for Active Directory environments

Answer (score -1):

```
Please go through the new changes and try the below mentioned settings.

LDAP 1.5 plugin is using Waffle to support Windows Authentication and SSO on Windows OS. 
LDAP in Windows auth mode supports two ways of login from browser: 

1.Single sign On  
SSO will be performed on hitting any SonarQube url other than /sessions/login . 
Only domain users are supported through SSO. 

2.Form based login from /sessions/login page 
Domain users  
Login: <domain\alias> or alias@domain or alias 
Password: <domain credentials> 

Technical users 
Login: <username> 
Password: <password> 

On logout, users will be presented login page ( /sessions/login), 
where he can choose to login as technical user or domain user by 
passing appropriate credentials. 

    For those users who are already using previous version of LDAP plugin to 
connect to Microsoft AD and have already defined authorization in terms of those 
users and group name use following settings in Windows OS: 


# LDAP configuration 
sonar.security.realm=LDAP 
ldap.windows.compatibilityMode=true
sonar.log.level=DEBUG (For debugging purpose, remove this if you don't see any issue)
ldap.windows.auth=true

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Default protocol is NTLM which should work for most of the scenarios. 
Troubleshooting NTLM 
◦Enabling NTLM Logging
http://goo.gl/3LhU6E

If you want to use Kerberos "Negotiate" protocol please use the following steps.

Negotiate Authentication Steps: 
For negotiate authentication to work make sure following steps are followed: 
1.Browser Configuration 
Waffle link: Configuring Browsers (IE/Firefox)
https://goo.gl/vcPnrk

2.Kerberos setup 
Make sure that user has privilege for Kerberos delegation 
setspn -L username 
To add preivileges to the current user run 
setspn -S HTTP/machine:port machine 
example: 
setspn -S HTTP/machine:9000 machine 

3.The SonarQube application is running as a service(NT service) 
Troubleshooting Resources 
1.Useful Kerberos troubleshooting resources 
◦Enabling Kerberos Logging
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262177/en-us
◦Troubleshooting Kerberos Delegation
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=4754
```

Comment: DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsUsersProvider] Requesting details for user: xxxxx
TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=select cq.uuid ...
TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=select cq.uuid ...
TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=select cq.uuid ...
TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=select cq.uuid ...
ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::Com4j::ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 8007203a Failed to MkParseDisplayName : The server is not operational. : .\com4j.cpp:217
TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()....
DEBUG web[http] POST /sessions/login | time=....ms

Comment: sonar.security.realm=LDAP  
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true  
ldap.servers=A,B  
ldap.A.url=ldap://A1:3268  
ldap.A.user.baseDn=OU=...,DC=...,DC=...,DC=...  
ldap.A.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))  
ldap.A.bindDn=...  
ldap.A.bindPassword=...  
ldap.A.group.baseDn=OU=...,DC=...,DC=...,DC=...  
ldap.A.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))  
ldap.A.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName  
ldap.B.url=ldap://B1:3268  
ldap.B.user.baseDn=OU=...,DC=...,DC=...,DC=...  
....  ldap.B.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName  
sonar.security.localUsers=....